# > < symbol occurs error while XML parsing in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have handle &, " symbols but I am stuck with greater than and less than symbols.

I want to store data in a table with the correct form.

```
Auto < Test
```

**in my XML while I am passing '<' symbol it occurs error same happen with '>' also**

[image: error while run my code]

XML that contain < >

```
'<root>
                                        <name>AutoTest!@$^&(<>|;%#~Org.</name>
                                    </root>'
```

My Try

```
DECLARE @OrgNames  NVARCHAR(MAX)=   '<root>
                                        <name>Auto < Test</name>
                                    </root>'

DECLARE @columnStr_XML XML 

SET @columnStr_XML = CAST('<root1>'+ 
                             REPLACE( REPLACE(@OrgNames, '&', 'ATampZ'), '"' , 'ATdouble') + 
                         '</root1>' AS xml )

SELECT f.x.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS name,
        CAST(NULL AS BIGINT) AS org_id
into #temp_name
FROM @columnStr_XML.nodes('/root1/root/name') f(x)
WHERE f.x.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)')<>''

UPDATE #temp_name
SET name = REPLACE (REPLACE(name, 'ATampZ', '&'), 'ATdouble' , '"')

SELECT * FROM #temp_name

DROP TABLE #temp_name
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What makes it impossible to continue with your solution and just add a couple of more REPLACEs of < and >

Comment: @siggemannen I have tried it but it gives the above error, as attached images.

Comment: So why not posting that code. Instead of posting something else

Comment: `<` isn't a valid standalone character in XML, it should be encoded as `&lt;`. `&` should be encoded as `&amp;` and `>` as `&gt;`. If you're receiving "XML" that contains standalone `<`, `>` and `&` characters like that then it's only XML-ish, it's not valid XML.

Comment: aha, now i understand. You have XML that contains XML but also contains some "junk" like unescaped <>. Well, then i'd say, you're pretty much doomed. Is XML always in <root><name>SomeName</name></root> format? or is it flexible

Comment: What you can do is: first replace all xml tags to something that removes <> from them. for example replace(replace(pseudoXML, '<root>', '$root¤'), '</root>', '$/root¤') etc. Then you can replace < > & with something, finally you replace the xml tags back to their original, and then you should be able to CAST it

Comment: @siggemannen I got answers as per your above suggestion.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: best-effort, split the xml parser error message, get the position of the erroneous character and escape it.. https://dbfiddle.uk/JN8hFN-X

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear where your parsing error comes from, executing the SQL?

You should decide, if you store only valid xml in your database or if it is also allowed to store invalid xml.

To only store valid xml, you should replace all characters that could mix up the xml in advance. Something like htmlentities() in PHP.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

When retrieving the data back from the parsed xml, you can use the opposite to get the original data back, e.g. html_entity_decode().

When storing of invalid xml should be allowed, you can set up your parser to end parsing in a defined state, telling that there is no valid xml.